# Laravel - query to join tables in Many to many relation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have the below tables

```
posts
    - id
    - name

categories
    - id
    - name

category_post
    - post_id
    - category_id
```

**Post.php**

```
public function Category()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

**Category.php**

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
}
```

A post may contain many categories.

I want to query all posts related to the categories of any given post in the **least number of database queries.**

For example, If a post belongs to three categories, I want to get all the posts related to that three categories. I could achieve this in 4 DB queries as below.

```
$post = Post::find(1);

$categoryIds = $post->category()->pluck('id');

$postIds = DB::table('category_post')
    ->whereIn('category_id', $categoryIds)
    ->pluck('post_id')
    ->unique();

$relatedPosts = DB::table('posts')
    ->whereIn('id', $postIds)
    ->get();
```

Any help would be highly appreciated to reduce DB queries or refactor the code in laravel way.
Thanks

Comment: Just as a note. If you're doing this because you believe that less queries mean better performance then this is false. It matters more what the queries do rather than how many of them there are, with the noteable exception of the data transfer cost which would only apply if the database is outside the server's local network of virtual local network.

Comment: @apokryfos yes I understand that. In this particular case, do you think there won't be any difference in performance between my code and yours, say for 25 categories and 5000 posts?

Comment: In this particular case I think the main advantage is saving memory on the webserver by not loading partial data to prepare the next query, in addition to not having to perform the first query to get the model if you already know the id. I think the time it takes for both methods will scale similarly since the major time consuming process is to "join" the posts table via the categories which is an unavoidable operation

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks for your detailed clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your given example can be written like:

```
$postWithRelatedPosts = Post::whereHas('category.post', function ($q) {
    $q->where('id', 1);
})->get();
```

This is a single query but has 2 sub-queries within it. It generates something like:

```
select * 
from `posts` 
where exists (
    select * 
    from `categories` inner join `category_post` on `categories`.`id` = `category_post`.`category_id` 
    where `posts`.`id` = `category_post`.`post_id` and exists (
         select * 
         from `posts` inner join `category_post` on `posts`.`id` = `category_post`.`post_id` 
         where `categories`.`id` = `category_post`.`category_id` and `id` = ?
    )

)
```

Comment: Thanks @apokryfos for the answer.  It worked exactly the way I wanted.